# Storing the drop-down options of a rails form & just using the variable in that form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, erb

I am building a rails app.

I have drop-down fields with same options in different forms. I would like to store the options in a separate location and just use the variable in the drop-down field instead of typing in the options in each form.

Please help me with a small code code snippet or point me to a code-base

Comment: You can always create a class/module with the options as a constant, or something like that, and then use it to generate your options from this array whenever you need it in the system.

Comment: Here are some helpful references on building forms in rails: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rails helper method [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) allows you to pass in arrays or hashes to create the options fields.

Using `select`, you'll then need to define data in an object that can be used in the relevant parts of your application. One way to do that is to use a module. For example:

```
module DropDownOptions
  def number_options
    {"One" => 1, "Two" => 2, "Three" => 3}
  end

  def foo_options
    {"Foo" => "Bar"}
  end
end
```

You'll then need to put that code in your app folder. I'd put it in `app/tools/drop_down_options.rb` if there was nowhere more obvious to put it.

Then you can add it to your helpers:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include DropDownOptions
end
```

And that will allow you to do this in a view:

```
<%= select("post", "number_id", number_options) %>
```

If you need to use the hash to convert back the other way in your model, you can include it there too:

```
class Post << ActiveRecord::Base
  include DropDownOptions
end
```

And then the `number_options` method will be available within a post instance. Allowing you to do something like this:

```
class Post << ActiveRecord::Base
  include DropDownOptions

  def number_label
    number_options.invert[number_id] if number_id?
  end
end
```

By putting the options into a module, you can use them wherever they are needed. For example, if you prefer to user presenters or decorators instead of helper methods, just include the module in those objects.